# find the matching items given in an array

Tags: actionscript-3

i don't understand arrays in functions, but how do you find the matching items given in an array? for example:

```
var fruit:Array = ["apples", "oranges", "grapes", "oranges", "apples", "grapes"];
```

how can i get it to show only the number of apples in the array?

Comment: so many ways to do the same thing :)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: yes, you could even convert the array to a String and use a RegExp to find the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply, you can do this:

```
private function getCount(fruitArray:Array, fruitName:String):int {
    var count:int=0;
    for (var i:int=0; i<fruitArray.length; i++) {
        if(fruitArray[i].toLowerCase()==fruitName.toLowerCase()) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

var fruit:Array = ["apples", "oranges", "grapes", "oranges", "apples", "grapes"];
var appleCount=getCount(fruit, "apples"); //returns 2
var grapeCount=getCount(fruit, "grapes"); //returns 2
var orangeCount=getCount(fruit, "oranges"); //returns 2
```

Comment: While this works, it will drain performance once you get many items in the array, and if you want to search for different items on more than one occasion.  It is much more efficient to get a list of counters and iterate over the array just once.

Comment: Not necessarily, if items are added to and removed from the list frequently. In order to maintain accurate counts, you'd have to recalculate this every time the array changes, and since Array doesn't give you any help in terms of telling you it has changed, it would be difficult/impossible to make sure this is in sync.

Comment: @weltraumpirat, you're right. But seeing as the OP's a noob, I posted something that he would be able to easily understand. I did think of your method too, +1 to you

Comment: @AmyBlankenship, yet another reason for using `ArrayCollection` if it's going to be changed frequently :)

Comment: @AmyBlankenship True, but you have to recalculate on change anyway - and it's still going to be less costly than calculating every time you want to look up counts.

Comment: I disagree. Consider the following: 1) in a game, you could be adding elements of various types on every frame (so, 30+ times/sec), but you might need to change the display of how many of each are present once or twice a second 2) There is NO WAY to control access to the contents of an Array--anything that has a reference to the Array can change what is in it, even if the Object that owns the Array has a getter/setter. So you don't physically have a hook where you could hang logic to update whenever the Array updates.

Comment: Well, you can easily implement an addToArray() method that does just that. It's an array of strings, mind you. Also, it does not really matter: Counting all the different strings in one loop will be more efficient than filtering for each query, regardless of how often the array is updated - it could be on enterFrame or periodically.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how many items are in the array, and how often you want to search for different items, it can get very costly to have a for loop iterate over the entire array, every time you want to count things (which would happen if you did what the other two answers suggest). You might want to have a count function that iterates over the array just once, and returns a **list of counters**, instead of a single number:

```
function countItems( arr:Array ) : Object {
    var counts : Object = {};

    for each ( var item : String in arr ) {
        if (counts.hasOwnProperty(item)) counts[item]++;
        else counts[item] = 1;
    }
    return counts;
}

var fruit:Array = ["apples", "oranges", "grapes", "oranges", "apples", "grapes"];
var counts : Object = countItems(fruit);

trace (counts["apples"]);  // => 2
trace (counts["oranges"]); // => 2
trace (counts["grapes"]);  // => 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function countOccurrences( haystack, needle ){
    var index : int = -1;
    var counter : int = -1;
    do{
        counter++;
        index = haystack.indexOf( needle, index + 1 );
    }while( index >= 0 );
    return counter;
}

var fruit:Array = ["apples", "oranges", "grapes", "oranges", "apples", "grapes"];

trace( countOccurrences( fruit, "apples" ) ); //outputs '2'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var stringToSearch:String = "apples";
var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp(/\b\b/.source+stringToSearch, "g");
var matches:Array = fruit.toString().match(pattern);
//
trace(matches.length);
```

Disclaimer: don't use this if you have many elements in your array (eg. fruit.length>1000): it is compact but it can be slower than any other solution posted here. Another thing to point out is that here I'm assuming your "matching items" are "strings".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
private function makeFilter(filterValue:String):Function {
   var fn:Function = function (obj:Object, index:int=0, arr:Array=[]):Boolean {
     if (String(obj)==filterValue) {
        return true;
     }
     return false;
   }
   return fn;
}

//somewhere else:
var filterFunction:Function = makeFilter('apples');
var appleCount:int = fruit.filter(filterFunction).length;
```

FYI, more about this approach: http://www.gasi.ch/blog/functional-actionscript-1/

Comment: i'm still new to all this, so everything is just confusing. i have no idea what is going on here, but thanks

Comment: I added a link you can go to for more information on this approach

Comment: @AmyBlankenship: 1. shouldn't makeFilter `return fn`? 2. shouldn't the last line be `var appleCount = fruit.filter(filterFunction).length` ?

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns is right.  Also, see my own answer: Iterating the entire array every time you want to search for a term is very inefficient - just counting *all* items *once* would be enough, unless the array changes.  And it is also much more efficient to increase counter variables than to create a new array of result values and then get its length, even though in your example, this is done by the VM and not in code.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship: appleCount is not a proper name, imho, since it doesn't contain a number. Oh, I liked very much the link you posted.

Comment: @AsTheWormTurns: you're right, and since Amy didn't notice it yet, I've gone ahead and edited her answer for her. :)

Comment: I did notice, and I did edit it. I'm not sure what is wrong on your end where you failed to see it.  Please note that someone's edit removed the .length in the line that calculates the applecount, which of course would not work. IOW, please make sure you understand the code before you edit it!

Comment: @AmyBlankenship: I can barely comment what I see... ;-) and I noticed no edit.

Comment: I think what might have happened is that the edit that removed the length parameter (which is why appleCount didn't contain a number) happened very close to when I edited it to return a function, so that person's errant change overwrote mine. Note that I've re-edited it to add the int type back in. You'll know that code posted under my name ISN'T entirely mine if the types are left off, since that's something I don't EVER do!

Comment: @AmyBlankenship: int? Can that function return a value below 0?

Comment: @AmyBlankenship: I tested your code and it returns error 1047 on this line: `var fn:Function = function (obj:Object, index:int=0, arr:Array=[]):Boolean` (maybe you can avoid initialization).

Comment: Yes, I think the arr:Array=null someone put in one of the edits would have avoided that, but I was writing code off the top of my head (note I said "something like this" not "exactly this") ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var matches = 0
var arrayMatcher = (array1, array2) => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= array1 - 1; i++) {
        var myFirstItem = array1[i];
        for (a = 0; a <= array2.length - 1; a++) {
            var mySecondItem = array2[a];
            if (mySecondItem === myFirstItem) {
                matches += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

I used this to find matches in a list of a patient's symptoms with a list of common symptoms for a certain disease and it worked for me. You could give it a try! :)